# How to exclude specific fields from JSON using groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I would like to exclude the items which don't have **productModel** property in the below JSON. How can we achieve this in groovy
I tried using **hasProperty** but not worked for me as expected. If possible can I get some sample snippet

I tried below code - but didn't work as I expected.

```
response.getAt('myData').getAt('data').getAt('product').hasProperty('productModel').each { println "result ${it}" }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
{
    "myData": [{
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "iPhone",
                    "productModel": "6s"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [{
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {}
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "iPhone",
                    "productModel": "7"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [{
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {}
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "Macbook"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [{
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {}
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "count": 3,
        "offset": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude specific fields from JSON object then you have to recreate it using filtered data. The crucial part takes these two lines (assuming that `json` variable in the below example stores your JSON as text):

```
def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def myData = root.myData.findAll { it.data.product.containsKey('productModel') }
```

What happens here is we access `root.myData` list and we filter it using `findAll(predicate)` method and predicate in this case says that only objects that have key `productModel` in path `data.product` are accepted. This `findAll()` method does not mutate existing list and that is why we store the result in variable `myData` - after running this method we will end up with a list of size 2.

In next step you have to recreate the object you want to represent as a JSON:

```
def newJsonObject = [
    myData: myData,
    metadata: [
        count: myData.size(),
        offset: 0
    ]
]

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(newJsonObject))
```

In this part we create `newJsonObject` and in the end we convert it to a JSON representation.

Here is the full example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''{
    "myData": [{
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "iPhone",
                    "productModel": "6s"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [{
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {}
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "iPhone",
                    "productModel": "7"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [{
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {}
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "Macbook"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [{
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {}
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "count": 3,
        "offset": 0
    }
}'''

def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def myData = root.myData.findAll { it.data.product.containsKey('productModel') }

def newJsonObject = [
    myData: myData,
    metadata: [
        count: myData.size(),
        offset: 0
    ]
]

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(newJsonObject))
```

And here is the output it produces:

```
{
    "myData": [
        {
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "iPhone",
                    "productModel": "6s"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [
                {
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {

            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "product": {
                    "productId": "apple",
                    "productName": "iPhone",
                    "productModel": "7"
                },
                "statusCode": "active",
                "date": "2018-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "links": [
                {
                    "productUrl": "test"
                },
                {
                    "productImage": "test"
                }
            ],
            "info": {

            }
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "count": 2,
        "offset": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there anyway if I want to show in json response which doesn't have productModel key